# Compare the input user quantity value with the quantity value from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

i have a problem that i don't know how to compare the quantity of user input with the quantity in the database so that if the user put the quantity over the quantity in the database it will come one alert that notice the user that the product have out of stock on that quantity.Below is my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('warda',$con) or die(mysql_error());


$page_title= 'View Your Shooping Cart';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  foreach( $_POST['qty'] as $key => $value)
  { 
    if (is_numeric ($value))
    {
        if(($value == 0) AND (is_numeric($value)))
        {
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
        }
        elseif(is_numeric($value)AND($value>0))
        {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$key]=$value;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
      print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
      print 'alert("Please insert the a number")'; 
      print '</script>';
      echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=viewcart.php">';
      exit();   
    }
  }

}


$empty = TRUE;
if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$value)
{
    if(isset($key))
    {
        $empty=FALSE;

    }
  }
 }
  //echo $empty.'nilai';`

 if(!$empty)
 {

$query ='SELECT * FROM product WHERE code IN (';//coding dalam database
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value)
{
    $query.="'".$key."'".',';
}

$query = substr($query,0,-1).')';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("error");
echo "<form action=\"viewcart.php\" method=\"POST\">";
 echo'<table width="800" align="center" cellpadding=4 cellspacing=0 border=0    align="center" class="style25">
<tr>
    <td align="center" width="30%"><b>Code</b></td>
    <td align="center" width="30%"><b>Name</b></td>
    <td align="center" width="10%"><b>Price</b></td>
    <td align="center" width="10%"><b>Quantity</b></td>
    <td align="center" width="10%"><b>Total</b></td>
    </tr>';
echo'<form action="viewcart.php" method="post">';

$total = 0 ;
while($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $subtotal = $_SESSION['cart']         [$row_Recordset1['code']]*$row_Recordset1['price'];
    $price = $row_Recordset1['price'];
    $total+=$subtotal;      
    echo"<tr>
        <td align=\"center\" width=\"30%\">{$row_Recordset1['code']}</td>
        <td align=\"center\" width=\"30%\"><input type=\"hidden\"size=\"3\"         `name=\"name\" value= \"{$row_Recordset1['name']}\">{$row_Recordset1['name']}  </td>`
        <td align=\"center\" width=\"10%\">"; 
        echo "RM " . number_format($price,2);
        echo"</td>
        <td align=\"center\" width=\"10%\"><input type=\"text\"size=\"3\"   name=\"qty[{$row_Recordset1['code']}]\" value=\"{$_SESSION['cart'] [$row_Recordset1['code']]}\"</td>";
    echo'<td align="center">RM'.number_format($subtotal,2).'</td>
            </tr>';             
}   


echo'<tr> 
<td colspan="4" align="right"><b>Total Price:<b></td>
<td align="right">RM'.number_format($total,2).'</td>
</tr>
</table>';
$_SESSION['total'] = $total;


echo "  <div align=\"center\"></p>
<input type=\"submit\"class=\"style1\"  name=\"submit\"                                           
                              value=\"Update My Cart\" />   </div>
        </form>
        <div align=\"center\"> 
          <form name=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action=\"carts.php\">
            <input type=\"submit\" class=\"style1\" name=\"checkout\" 

      value=\"Checkout\"></p>";


 `?>`
 </form>

 <a href="m_custproducts.php">Continue Shopping</a>

        </div>
  <?php

$today = date("d-m-Y"); 

mysql_close();
}
else
{

        echo 'YOUR CART IS EMPTY';
  }



  ?>
```

Comment: First thing to learn: Java is like JavaScript, in the same way as a Car is the same as a Carpet. There is no Java code in this snippet, so better mark it as JavaScript or JQuery.

Comment: you need to use ajax.

Comment: unfortunately,i do not know how to used ajax.. :( Manish Shukla

Comment: Suppose there is 10 store in db and user enter 11 then you want to show an alert. And the value 10 is from Database. is that you want ?

Comment: yes it is..i want to notify user that the value they input is over than the quantity in database.so they can't proceed with checkout.

Comment: the value is entered by user is single or is an array

Comment: yes, it is an array..

Comment: Trust me when I say, stop what you're doing and learn Ajax.

Comment: i dont have soo much time to learn about ajax.. i have to complete my final year project by this week bcoz my prsntation is around the corner.. please help me.. :'(

Comment: @JoeSwindell There is no **need** for ajax here. You could just add a `data-quantity` attribute to the input when the page is first generated. As a side note, you should no longer use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.

Comment: "i have to complete my final year project by this week". Maybe it is a bit late ? We are not going to do it for you. You haven't tried anything to do it.

Comment: Apart from what @Brewal is saying, you should learn about SQL injection and how to prevent it, because your code is subject to it: you sanitize the values but not the keys, and then use the keys in dynamic SQL statements. You should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), **AND** prepared statements instead.